# ItemTemplateSelector binding to templated parent property

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I have some 3rd party control, and I am setting a Template property for this control. I do the following inside the ControlTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

This works OK. Now, what I need to do is apply 1 additional template in a particular case. This means that I need to use ItemTemplateSelector, where I would define two templates.

First thing first, I would like to have exactly the same behavior using ItemTemplateSelector as with ItemTemplate (as in above code).

```
<local:SomeTemplateSelector x:key="a"
                            DefaultTemplate="{what here}" />
```

to have equivalent to this line:

```
ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
```

**Edit**: here is a more detailed example of usage:

```
<SomeControl>
      <SomeControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="SomeControl">
          <SomeItemsControl ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <SomeItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </SomeItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              </SomeItemsControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </SomeControl.Template>
    </SomeControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

A static resource with an x:key which is your default template, assuming your `TemplateSelector` implements `DataTemplateSelector` and has a PropertyCalled `DefaultTemplate`.

- when is the default template is selected?

thats something that you decide in your `SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)` method of your TemplateSelector.

here is an example:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<VMBase> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<VMBase>() { new Model1(), new Model2(), new Model3() };
}

public class SomeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Template1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template2 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Model1)
            return Template1;
        else if (item is Model2)
            return Template2;
        else
            return DefaultTemplate; //or return null if you need the default template of the control
    }
}

public class VMBase{}

public class Model1 : VMBase{}

public class Model2 : VMBase{}

public class Model3 : VMBase{}
```

XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="defaultTemplate">
            <TextBlock>defaultTemplate</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
            <TextBlock>Template1</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
            <TextBlock>Template2</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:SomeTemplateSelector x:Key="SomeTemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}"
                                                                 Template1="{StaticResource Template1}"  
                                                                 Template2="{StaticResource Template2}">

        </local:SomeTemplateSelector>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SomeTemplateSelector}"></ListBox>
```

if you want the default template of a given element to be applied the just return null from the SelectTemplate method.

Comment: As I said, a first step is to implement the exact functionality as with ItemTemplate binding. So lets assume that DataTemplateSelector will always return DefaultTemplate. Can you provide an example how should DefaultTemplate look like, to have the same functionality as ItemTemplate in above example (I am not interested in code for DataTemplateSelector).

Comment: As I said in the last comment, I am not interested in code for DataTemplateSelector. I need the code for DefaultTemplate, which will have the exact functionality as the code where I did binding to ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Goran the default template for some ui element you get by returning null from the SelectTemplate  method

Comment: @Goran also if you don't like returning a null for some reason then keep the DefaultTemplate property in the Selector and set it in the as XAML as `DefaultTemplate="{x:Null}"`

Comment: This is not an answer to a question. If you read the question again, the key is in the first code example I gave. ItemsControl is getting the ItemTemplate from its parent control (3rd party control). When using an ItemTemplateSelector, I need to set DefaultTemplate to the same ItemTemplate from the parent control. I cannot use TemplateBinding in this scenario. So the question really is: how can I convert the first example in question to use ItemTemplateSelector instead of ItemTemplate? I am only interested in xaml code (the actual template).

Comment: I have edited the question to give you a more detailed scenario. The question is how can I convert that code to use ItemTemplateSelector?

Comment: @Goran if your problem is the `ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"` part its actually the equivelent of `ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"`other wise i don't really understand the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75338/discussion-between-goran-and-decoherence).